# Running functions in R multiple times during benchmarking

Tags: function, r, benchmarking

I am trying to measure the computation time of a function in R using `system.time()`. 
I want to run the function a few hundred times to get an average but I don't want
to copy and paste that many times. Is there an easier way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The microbenchmark package takes a `,times=` option and has the added bonus of being a bit more accurate.

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> m <- microbenchmark( seq(10)^2, (1:10)^2, times=10000)
> m
Unit: nanoseconds
       expr   min    lq median    uq     max
1  (1:10)^2  2567  3423   3423  4278   41918
2 seq(10)^2 44484 46195  46195 47051 1804147
> plot(m)
```

[image: plot microbenchmark]

And using the not-yet-released autoplot() method for ggplot2:

```
autoplot(m)
```

[image: autoplot microbenchmark]

Comment: I like to plot it in lattice with either `require(lattice); bwplot(expr~time, m, auto.key=TRUE, xlim=quantile(v$time,c(0,0.95)))` or `require(latticeExtra); ecdfplot(~time, groups=expr, m, auto.key=TRUE, xlim=quantile(v$time,c(0,0.95)))`.

Comment: @Marek I agree the default plot looks terrible....  When I used it the other day in an actual example I used `ggplot` and did quartiles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/6871968#6871968

Comment: Just a note that `autoplot.microbenchmark` as used above is now available in `taRifx` 1.0.3, which should be available on CRAN within the next few hours.

Answer (score 12):

```
system.time(replicate (  ... stuff ..) )
```

Or: (hey, I'm not ashamed to have the same answer as Dirk.)

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark( stuff... )   # Nice for comparative work
```

Answer (score 11):

You want to use the [rbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rbenchmark) package and its function `benchmark()` which does just about everything for you.

Here is the first example from its help page:

```
R> example(benchmark)

bnchmrR> # example 1
bnchmrR> # benchmark the allocation of one 10^6-element numeric vector, 
bnchmrR> # replicated 100 times
bnchmrR> benchmark(1:10^6)
    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 1:10^6          100   0.327        1      0.33        0          0         0
```

For truly expression-level benchmarking, there is also the [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/package=microbenchmark) package.