# unexpected results: microbenchmark

Tags: r, microbenchmark

I've always been bugged a bit by the lack of accuracy I see bench marking with `system.time` and `rbenchmark` (in that the precision of the timing may be lacking) and saw Hadley reference the `microbenchmark` package recently.  So I decided to give it a whirl as seen below.  I pitted `mean` against `f <- function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)}` and expected `mean` to do way better than `f` but the results, as I understand them, do not indicate this to be true.

1. Am I misunderstanding the results?
2. Is f actually faster than mean?
3. Is microbenchmark still in a beta phase and this needs to be ironed
   out?

I'm running R2.15 on a win 7 machine (as microbenchmark does timings differently depending on your OS).

**The Results**

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr    min     lq median     uq    max
1    f(x) 19.130 20.529 20.529 20.996 286.00
2 mean(x) 28.927 29.860 30.327 30.327 672.31
```

**The Code**

```
library(microbenchmark)

x <- 1:10000
f <- function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)}
mean(x)

res <- microbenchmark(
    mean(x), 
    f(x), 
times=1000L)

print(res)
boxplot(res)
```

Comment: I like `microbenchmark`.  If you're doing more than one or two results, plotting can help greatly but the default output is a little on the ugly side.  I wrote an autoplot function for ggplot2 which may show up in one of these releases (check github in the meantime). Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6919493/636656

Comment: This may explain it http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/inaccurate-results-from-microbenchmark/

Comment: Probably not as all stats for the `f` were lower and a scatterplot indicated this as well.  joran nailed this one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could be wrong, but this doesn't seem all that surprising to me. Before `mean.default` can call `.Internal(mean(x))` it has to check 3 `if` statements, calculate the length of `x`, and then check another `if` statement. And the difference in times it fairly small.

Calling `.Internal(mean(x)` directly is slightly faster still:

```
library(microbenchmark)

x <- 1:10000
f1 <- function(x) {sum(x)/length(x)}
f2 <- function(x) {.Internal(mean(x))}

res <- microbenchmark(
    mean(x), 
    f1(x),
    f2(x), 
times=1000L)

print(res)

Unit: microseconds
     expr    min      lq  median      uq     max
1   f1(x) 32.195 32.4605 32.8850 33.4645 106.997
2   f2(x) 21.840 22.0580 22.2015 22.6270  55.316
3 mean(x) 35.393 35.9840 36.1860 36.4420  91.203
```

Comment: Thanks.  I made an assumption and didn't check it.  A better check of microbenchmarking would be `sum` against a `Reduce` version: `sum2 <- function(x) Reduce("+", x)`  which yields the expected results.  I think I'm going to like `microbenchmark`

Comment: Just ran across this in unrelated readings.  Apparently mean is somewhat notorious: http://lookingatdata.blogspot.se/2011/04/speeding-up-r-computations.html

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that if you bump up the size of X by a factor of 10 you'll see more consistent results.  To be honest I'd be surprised if you really can get micro-second timing accuracy on a computer with a multi-tasking operating system.

You might also consider:

- Are you running on a laptop or a machine which has automatic CPU frequency scaling?
- Warmup?
- Pinning your process to one core.

Comment: Part of the beauty of `microbenchmark` is that it runs things a lot of times so you can see how the results vary, so I'd guess that what's running in the background has no effect on the results in expectation.

Comment: @gsk3 have a look at the output times, and you'll see a long tail, so something like...  hist(res[res$expr=='f(x)','time']/length(x), breaks=90)

Comment: @gsk3 it depends what the question is I suppose.  How fast can it go? or How fast will it go on "average"? :)